# What is x86_thread_state64_t & thread_act_t?

Tags: macos, architecture, x86, darwin

I was looking into source code of [StarRuntime](https://github.com/StarProject/StarRuntime) and I came across two terms x86_thread_state64_t & thread_act_t.

I tried to Google it but there is not much documentation. 
I see it being used consistently in apple open source projects?
Can someone explain me what are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x86_thread_state64_t should be something like this

```
struct x86_thread_state64_t {
    uint64_t rax, rbx, rcx, rdx,
             rdi, rsi, rbp, rsp,
             r8, r9, r10, r11,
             r12, r13, r14, r15,
             rip, rflags,
             cs, fs, gs;
};
```

and

thread_act_t is

```
struct thread  *thread_act_t;
```

Comment: On my machine, x86_thread_state64_t is typedef'd in /usr/include/mach/i386/thread_status.h, and refers to _STRUCT_X86_FLOAT_STATE64 in /usr/include/mach/i386/_structs.h. The purpose of that structure is to capture the current state of the CPU's primary registers. Very useful for debugging/crash reporting/etc.